# How to mask unique attributes in script tag

Tags: node.js, proxy

I have a remote chat script file that is passing in unique tokens in the script tag.  One issue with this apporach is anyone can reuse this script tag with my unique parameters to access the chat which I do not want.  How can I mask these ids so they are not visible on the client-side.

```
<script src="https://www.website.com/chat.js" channelId="8adf8b3" token="12345"></script>
```

I have attempted to create a Node proxy that gets the request but I am not sure how to capture that attribute value and forward it on to the URL.  This code also presents a HTTP 403 error.

```
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ proxyOptions });
app.get('/*', cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
    const targetUrl = config.proxyForwardingUrl + req.url;
    console.log(targetUrl);
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: targetUrl });
});
```

Is a proxy server the best approach or is there another way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done with tokens that expire. One good example is jwt tokens. Those tokens are signed via private key therefore cannot be changed/manipulated by user without server knowing about it.

Jwt tokens contain timestamp when it will expire and server knows when to close web socket and/or reject any requests from client using expired token.

Flow usually is:

1. Client logs in webpage and  receives token
2. Using token it connects to different resources
3. When token is close to expiration it asks for new token then go to step to
4. When token is not issued server starts to close all resources

This is how you can protect yourself from leaking secrets, even thought villain acquires token he will not be able to use the resource or only for small time.

Usually token lifespan for chats/streams are under a minute.

[Here](https://jwt.io/introduction/) you can read about JWT more.

**Is there a way to hide this JWT token from client to not be able to see or acquire it?**

I'm not aware for any methods that does that. One think you can do is [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) it, but it still can be decoded. Compared to JWT tokens, they are not possible to break, because they are signed with [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) key which are safe and are used all around internet.